# Unable to set property in header using HTTPUrlConnection in GET request

Tags: java, rest, header

I tried to found a solution for this, even found numerous solutions but none resolved my issue.
I am trying to implement a Java client which will consume a `Restful web service` .
I want to set parameters inside header which I can retrieve on my web server. My code is;

```
URL url = new URL("http://servierIP/address");

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);

conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("firstParam", "hi");
conn.addRequestProperty("secondParam","12345" );

conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
conn.connect();
```

However, when I try to get values from header, I get `NULL` . 
I tried to do it with `addRequestProperty` and `setRequestProperty` both, but still the values are not getting set inside my header.

and the output I am getting when I try to fetch header value is:

```
 null : [HTTP/1.1 200 OK]
 Expires : [Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT]
 Access-Control-Allow-Orgin : [*]
 Set-Cookie : [dsfjskfjdsfjskf  ---- some value]
 Access-Control-Allow-Methods : [*]
 Connection : [Keep-Alive]
 Server : [Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)]
 X-Powered-By : [PHP/5.3.3]
 Cache-Control : [no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0, public, public]
 Pragma : [no-cache, public, public]
 Date : [Tue, 26 Aug 2014 05:33:10 GMT]
 Transfer-Encoding : [chunked]
 Content-Type : [application/xml; charset=utf-8]
```

If anyone can resolve the issue, I would be very grateful..

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding header for HttpURLConnection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection)

Comment: I already went through this post but it didn't work out for me...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [Apache http client](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi)?
Adding headers is quite simple

```
DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
httpget.addHeader("my-custom-header", "value");
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget);
```

Comment: Will I be able to fetch this header value on my server code ? Because right now, When i try to fetch the header , it won't show the value there.

Comment: yes, you will be able to fetch the header at the server side. And since you are using `php 5.3.3` you might want to have a look at [this](http://www.omaroid.com/php-get-and-set-custom-http-headers/) post too.