# new to java - need to do POST with Basic authentication header

Tags: java, android, web-services, http

I need to do a `POST` command using `httpurlconnect` preferably using a Basic authentication header.

Here are the specs:

The REST APIs listed below require authentication, all the requests must include a HTTP Basic Authentication header.

```
username = "WKD4N7YMA1uiM8V"
```

and

```
psrwd: DtdTtzMLQlA0hk2C1Yi5pLyVIlAQ68
```

All the HTTP requests must also include this custom header: `X-AppGlu-Environment: staging`.

It should query [this endpoint](https://api.appglu.com/v1/queries/findRoutesByStopName/run) to get the results:

```
POST https://api.appglu.com/v1/queries/findRoutesByStopName/run
Body: { "params": { "stopName": "%lauro linhares%" } }
```

Some streets for testing are: Delminda Silveira, Mauro Ramos, Governador Irineu Bornhausen, Deputado Antônio Edu Vieira.

Comment: sorry i dint add any code, but all my code is jacked up.. no point of even posting;

Comment: This is answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection