# Downloaded File Has 0 Bytes

Tags: java, file, download

I'm trying to download a `.mp3` music file from [this URL](https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary_download?vid=d0a68933f592c297) to the project root directory but the downloaded file always has 0 bytes in size (it is blank). The download also immediately stops.

I'm using the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

public class MusicDownloader
{
    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        download("https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary_download?vid=d0a68933f592c297", "Ponies and Balloons");
    }

    public static void download(String url, String fileName) throws MalformedURLException, IOException
    {
        FileUtils.copyURLToFile(new URL(url), new File(fileName + ".mp3"));
    }
}
```

In a browser, downloading the file manually works flawlessly. A download link from another website e.g. [this one](http://freedownloads.last.fm/download/569264057/Get%2BGot.mp3) had no problems to be processed by the code. What could be the problem here?

[Sending a valid user-agent String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25630202/couldnt-download-image) doesn't work either.

Comment: I haven't checked, but it's possible that Youtube is doing redirects and Apache Commons IO isn't following them.

Comment: @Powerlord:
Which code/approach would you suggest to consider/detect redirects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is actually with your URL `https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary_download?vid=d0a68933f592c297`. It is actually issuing a redirect as **Resource Temp Moved - 301** status code. So you need to pick its new `URL`. I tried using it `HttpURLConnection` to see that new redirected url is `https://youtube-audio-library.storage.googleapis.com/d0a68933f592c297`. You can use the below code :-

```
String urlString = "https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary_download?vid=d0a68933f592c297";
        URL url = new URL(urlString);
        HttpURLConnection huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        int statusCode = huc.getResponseCode(); //get response code
        if (statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP
                || statusCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM){ // if file is moved, then pick new URL
            urlString = huc.getHeaderField("Location");
            url = new URL(urlString);
            huc = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
        }
        System.out.println(urlString);  
        InputStream is = huc.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("test.mp3");
        int i = 0;
        while ((i = bis.read()) != -1)
            fos.write(i);
```

The same effect you can check is available in `FileUtils`  or not. I am sure, it should be . Cheers :)

Comment: You're amazing Sir!
I'm getting status code `303 See Other` so I had to adapt your code but it works ;)

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza glad that it helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer @AnkitNigam. I was having the same issue where the URLs were being redirected and your code worked perfectly.

Comment: @evaldeslacasa glad that it helped :)

Answer (score -3):

Because it is illegal and against [Youtube Terms of Service](https://www.youtube.com/static?template=terms)

Youtube specifically blocks most generic ways of downloading mp3 off their site. A simple 10ish lines of code won't work or piracy would've been bigger than it already is.

If they catch you, you **WILL** be blocked

Comment: No, it isn't because it's their free audio library that anyone can download. They even provide download links themselves here: https://www.youtube.com/audiolibrary/music

Comment: using a third party program/alternative method is. That's what the link is for

Comment: I honestly don't want to click download a 100 times. They should have made a way to just download everything and this is what I'm about to do

Comment: I like your bio details on your profile page, :),but, your answer is totally incorrect

Comment: @BullyWiiPlaza why don't you work at Youtube and tell them that.