# HTTP error code : 400

Tags: java, rest, http-headers

I am trying to download a file from REST url. Here is the code that I use

```
byte[] plainCredsBytes ="mytoken".getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
URL url = new URL("https://api.xxxxx.com/files/62645/6hSFcVs3qIbvrGdXOfYzXQ/Test.png");
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
```

I am getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400

I tried to get more details from the response and here it is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error>
<Code>InvalidArgument</Code>
<Message>Only one auth mechanism allowed; only the X-Amz-Algorithm query parameter, Signature query string parameter or the Authorization header should be specified</Message>
<ArgumentName>Authorization</ArgumentName>
<ArgumentValue>Basic M2U3YzMzODU3NmY3ZjgwNzY2OWU5Yzg5NDg0Y2Y3Mzc=     </ArgumentValue>
<RequestId>7BDEA0EBE74A63FF</RequestId>
<HostId>qU+xjS3nRcTbyBHPZyM89tGZC46sa9XzhkDLPD+p4oOSQc1UF9vSnpqB7A6Mlp5s76iqCOY2n+0=</HostId>
</Error>
```

I am passing basic authorization credentials, if I remove it I get
HTTP error code : 401 {"message":"Requires authentication"}

Any help?

Comment: How are you setting base64Creds variable? Can you post that code?

Comment: @user2953113 modified code to include it

Comment: This could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection

Comment: Try username + ":" + password.                                                                 String userCred = username + ":" + password;
String encodedAuthorization = Base64.encodeBase64(userCred.getBytes());

Comment: @ user2953113 I tried with user name:password it did not work

Comment: @the-neo-noir-developer I saw the earlier tried same answer but still gettiing the same error

Comment: Are you getting 401 or 400 error ?

Comment: @the-neo-noir-developer400, if I comment this line conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds); I get 401

Comment: Are you sure the username/password is valid? Did you check with the owner of the REST endpoint?

Comment: @user2953113 The same url and credentials works when I try from advanced rest client in chrome

Comment: Can you try "application/octet-stream" as "Accept" and update the observation.

Comment: @the-neo-noir-developer no change I get the same code and error message

Comment: One more question, how do you know the name of the path to be 6hSFcVs3qIbvrGdXOfYzXQ ?

Comment: @the-neo-noir-developer I get the path as response of another REST url

Comment: Was just curios if that id in the path is a generated id, and it would keep changing , in that case the authentication would not be required. But that would depend on the rest implementation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90645/discussion-between-the-neo-noir-developer-and-fjkjava).

Comment: Try this too. `byte[] plainCredsBytes ="mytoken".getBytes("UTF-8");`

Comment: @user2953113 still no luck

Comment: Since it works in rest client, can you compare the request headers sent from rest client vs the request headers sent from the java client? fiddler is a good tool for this purpose.

Comment: This is what i see on REST client                                                  Request headers 
CSP: active
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8 
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Comment: I tried with same headers on my java client but did not see any change

Comment: Can you compare the Authorization header in REST client vs Authorization header in java client?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90657/discussion-between-fjkjava-and-user2953113).

Comment: Basic auth header should be `Basic base64encode(username:password)`, notice the `username:password`

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 400 Bad request because the service I invoked verifies my authentication and redirects it to an amazon service which does not require authentication so it was complaining about the request.

I had to disable the follow redirect and get the location then send another request to get the file

```
conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
```

Actually the above program I did for poc, my actual client is using spring rest template. Default implementation for ClientHttpRequestFactory does setInstanceFollowRedirects(true) for GET so I had to create a custom ClientHttpRequestFactory.

```
public class CustomClientHttpRequestFactory extends SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory {

@Override
protected void prepareConnection(HttpURLConnection connection, String httpMethod) throws IOException {
    .....
}
```

}