# I need to deny the login to my server from previous app version made in Cordova

Tags: php, android, web-services, cordova

I have made an app in javascript using Apache Cordova, and now i´m gonna use a new one written in java.

my app communicates with a php webservice, so, what are my options to deny the previous app to login ?

1. I think one option may be versioning  the new one and consulting  it for every time that a login its requested.

but at the moment, I don't know ..

note: the previous app is distributed via email to the workers so I can't just update from a server and replace it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your Java client add a header when talking to your webservice, possibly a specific user agent. Or have it send a accept header which includes a version:

```
GET /jobs HTTP/1.1
Host: api.example.com
Accept: application/vnd.example.api+json;version=2
```

Your webservice can check the presence of the Accept header and the version string in it and decide what to do based on that.

You could return a value that is compatible with the old client and a different value that is compatible with the new client. or you can simply return a 404 or a 501 status code with an error message to the old client.

The generic process is explained here in detail:

- http://labs.qandidate.com/blog/2014/10/16/using-the-accept-header-to-version-your-api/

Applying this to PHP and Java is relatively simple:

- Java: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555952/736079
- PHP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/541463/736079

As an alternative you can add a version value to your request using a post variable, querystring parameter or as part of the request body (in JSON). I personally like it less than the use of accept headers, since the last is more flexible in the long run. You can even add multiple values to an accept header to indicate which versions you support. Your server can reply with the version it responded with. Giving you a better long-term solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a custom `var` to the url the new app is accessing, .i.e:

```
http://somesite/verify.php?whichApp=v2
```

Then you can use something like:

**verify.php**

```
<?
if(isset($_GET['whichApp'])){
    if($_GET['whichApp'] !== "v2"){
      die("Old Version");
   }
}
```