# Converting a CURL Request to a HTTP Request Java

Tags: java, curl, httprequest

I have the following CURL request Can anyone please confirm me what would be the subesquest HTTP Request

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" --data-urlencode "model=" --data-urlencode "imageurl.img.com" apiurl.api.com
```

What I tried:

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
conn.setDoInput(true);
conn.setDoOutput(true);


conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

String payload = "model=\"\"&url=" + url;

OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
writer.write(payload);
writer.close();
```

The problem is I keep getting a 403 HTTP Error code.
It works with CURL, so I might not be converting it right.

What can I do to make the conversion?

@EDIT

API: http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#Change_Skin
Mojang's Example:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" --data-urlencode "model=" --data-urlencode "url=http://assets.mojang.com/SkinTemplates/steve.png" https://api.mojang.com/user/profile/<uuid>/skin
```

Comment: I mean the better use exist library in java, for example: https://github.com/libetl/curl

Comment: I notice a comment at http://wiki.vg/Talk:Mojang_API: “How exactly should the payload look like? Whatever I send (even garbage data) I get back a 403 HTTP response with `{"error":"Forbidden","errorMessage":"Current IP not secured"}`. Have you tried running the suggested `curl` command and does it give you the response you expect? Or does it instead also give you a 403? You can prepend `-i` to it to see the status code and headers from the response: `curl -i -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>"…`

Answer (score 1):

The `curl` invocation in the question causes the POST body to be `model=&imageurl.img.com`:

```
$ curl --trace-ascii - -H "Authorization: Bearer <access token>" \
  --data-urlencode "model=" --data-urlencode "imageurl.img.com" https://example.com

=> Send header, 183 bytes (0xb7)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: Host: example.com
0024: User-Agent: curl/7.51.0
003d: Accept: */*
004a: Authorization: Bearer <access token>
0070: Content-Length: 23
0084: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
00b5:
=> Send data, 23 bytes (0x17)
0000: model=&imageurl.img.com
== Info: upload completely sent off: 23 out of 23 bytes
```

Specifically that `curl` invocation doesn’t include a `url=` param.

In contrast, the Java seems to cause the POST body to be `model=""&url=imageurl.img.com`—assuming other code (not shown in the question) sets the `url` variable to `imageurl.img.com`.

I guess it could instead be that there’s no code which sets the`url` variable to `imageurl.img.com`. There’s no way to tell from just the snippet in the question.

Also the `curl` invocation sends the header `Accept: */*` while the Java code instead sends the header `Accept: application/json`. I wouldn’t think that’d cause a 403 but who knows.

Also, the `curl` invocation sends a `User-Agent: curl/7.51.0` header, but it’s not clear if the Java code is causing a `User-Agent` header to be sent. I’d assume it is, but again, who knows.

Comment: The actual API I'm trying to use can be found here http://wiki.vg/Mojang_API#Change_Skin.

I'll update the question with their example

Comment: Their example is what I'm sortta trying to replicate with Java

Answer (score -1):

You are setting properties but should specify headers.

Comment: and how can i do that?

Comment: @MoisesCol seems I'm wrong.  Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection