# HttpURLConnection header

Tags: java, json, header, httpurlconnection

I am new to user java to connect to server. I have succeed in forming a json which has some key and value to form the body to call the api service and get successful response (with the following code).
My questions are:

1. Some of my web service just request header info, for example, I just need to 
   put the ApiKey(key name) and key value in the header and send to server, no other info is needed in body, how can I do this?
2. Some of my web service require both header info and body info, how can I construct the json and send to server? 
      try {

   ```
       String input = jsonString;
       URL url = new URL("https://example.com");
       HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
       conn.setDoOutput(true);
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
       OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
       os.write(input.getBytes());
       os.flush();
       System.out.println("errorcode" + conn.getResponseCode());

       if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), "Please input a correct username or password");
           return;
       }

       BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
               (conn.getInputStream())));

       String jsonText = read(br);
       System.out.println("jsonText: " + jsonText);
   ```

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection

Comment: You have solution in your code itself, learn more about HttpURLConnection.setRequestProperty   https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#setRequestProperty(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding header for HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection)

Comment: @Scar  I have read that post before,  and I got some error when I modify the code
SEVERE: null
java.lang.RuntimeException: Request Failed. HTTP Error Code: 411