# basic authentication json android

Tags: android, json, authentication, connection

I'm trying to access some json data, from a website. It has basic authentication, so i can't access the data and receive the exception: Filenotfoundexception. I now i'm in the right path, but i need help for the last steps. My code is:

```
private class jsonConnection extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {

        String username = "---";
        String password = "---";
        String credentials = username + ":" + password;

        String sensorID = "sensors";
        String api = "api";
        String webURL = "https://" + credentials + "@---";

        String credBase64 = Base64.encodeToString(credentials.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT).replace("\n", "");

        try {

            URL url = new URL(webURL + "/" + sensorID + "/" + api);

            System.out.println(url);
            System.out.println(credentials);

            connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();


            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            connection.setReadTimeout(30000);
            connection.setConnectTimeout(30000);

            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoInput(true);

            connection.addRequestProperty("HTTP_Authorization", "basic" + credentials);

            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

            //StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while (line != null) {
                line = bufferedReader.readLine();
                data = data + line;
            }

            //  JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            //  jsonObject.put("coord", coord);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

i know this code is enough to establish a connection to any other JSON data, but since there's basic authentication i cant seem to connect to this website's json. I appreciate the help beforehand!

Comment: Your authorization header is not adequate. Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15555952).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 

Do you know why this line is marked in red:

String basicAuth = "Basic " + new String(new Base64().encode(credentials.getBytes()));

Comment: Only Base64().encode(credentials.getBytes()) is marked in red, but there are no available solutions when alt + enter the code. Do i need to import a library?

Comment: "error: Base64() is not public in Base64; cannot be accessed from outside package"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection/15555952#comment31180814_15555952

Comment: Thanks man! Fixed my problem. Appreciated!!