# How to Pass header attributes via java.net.URL

Tags: java, java-io

I am using a third party API in my program who's job is to construct a SOAP message  by using the java.net.URL object passed as an input. I am constructing the URL object by passing the url as a String and thats it.

The requirement now is to attach a header to the URL before passing it to the third party API. My challenge is the API takes only URL as an input and nothing else. AS i have exhausted all my options, can you please let me know if there is any workaround or options available that can be applied in this scenario?

Comment: Can you post code for more details

Comment: @Santhosh The code looks like below.
URL urlObj = new URL("http://localhost:8080");
ThirdPartyAPI obj = new ThirdPartyAPI(urlObj);

now i am trying to figure our how to attach the header information to the urlObj.

Comment: I think you forgot to put the code

Comment: Your understanding of the URL is not right. A URL is a locater and it will never have headers. Do you mean HttpUrlConnection or SOAP message? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL

Comment: If you are trying to connect to that URL use this link to set headers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection

Else if its a soap request you need to set the SOAPHeader

Comment: @Santhosh, thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, urlObject is the only option i have to pass it to the API.I can not construct HttpURLConnection and pass its reference to the API.

Answer (score 2):

```
URL urlObj = new URL(url);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod(method.toUpperCase());
connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "BASIC "+new String(encodedBase64));
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.connect();
```

This is how I did it with my URL object
`setRequestProperty` will add Key-Value pair to the Header of the Request.