# How to pass your username and password in a get request with groovy?

Tags: java, groovy

I send GET request and receive error 500

```
 def baseUrl = new URL(url)
         HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) baseUrl.openConnection();
         connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "user1 user1")
         connection.addRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json")
         connection.with {
           doOutput = true
           requestMethod = 'GET'
           println content.text
         }
```

I am sure that my api work true.

How to pass your username and password in a get request with groovy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding header for HttpURLConnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection)

Comment: @cfrick, no
I receive error: No signature of method: static java.util.Base64.encode() is applicable for argument types: ([B, java.lang.Integer) values: [[117, 115, 101, 114, 49, 58, 117, 115, 101, 114, 49], 0]

Comment: `new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode("secret".getBytes()))` - as in the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you wrote the `"Authorization"` header is incorrect. For basic authentication, you need to encode the username and password and use it alongside the `"Basic"` keyword.

```java
import java.net.HttpUrlConnection
import java.net.URL
import java.util.Base64.Encoder

def baseUrl = new URL("https://myurl.com")
def credentials = "user1 user1"
def encodedCredentials = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(credentials.getBytes())
...
connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + encodedCredentials.toString())
...
```