# Convert Axios Node.js HTTPS POST request to Java HTTPURLConnection

Tags: java, http, axios, ssl-certificate

I'm seeking guidance on converting an Axios Node.js HTTPS POST request to Java using HTTPURLConnection or a suitable Java library for handling HTTPS requests.

Here is the Node.js code I'm trying to convert:

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const { readFileSync } = require('fs');
const https = require('https');

let data = JSON.stringify({
    "version": "1.0",
});

let config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'https://example.com/api/endpoint',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer token',
    },
    data: data,
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
        cert: readFileSync('path/to/certificate.crt'),
        key: readFileSync('path/to/private_key.key'),
    })
};

axios.request(config)
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

I've made attempts to research and convert this functionality to Java, exploring HTTPURLConnection and other libraries. However, I haven't been successful in replicating the HTTPS POST request functionality, especially handling headers and SSL configuration in Java.

Could someone provide guidance or a Java code example demonstrating how to perform a similar HTTPS POST request securely in Java? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: (More or less) URL |--> URLConnection |--> Cast to HttpsURLConnection |--> set doInput/output |--> addRequestProperty (headers) |--> getOutputStream |--> write |--> getInputStream |--> read [ refer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732422/adding-header-for-httpurlconnection ] Also refer: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html and follow the links to the classes